# Infinite Scrolling in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Currently I have infinite scrolling implemented on my side project and it works completely fine on chrome browser for the desktop. However, when you transition over to the mobile chrome browser, the script does not work when you reach bottom of the screen.

[Here is the site that has the same script for reaching end of the screen](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-web-gallery/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
alert($(document).height());

}
});
```

[Example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcKVK/1/)`

Thank You all for the help!

Comment: Try jQuery waypoints plugin - imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: I was hoping to avoid plugins and just do it with javascript only